# Storing API data in Json fromat

Tags: python, arrays, json, dataframe, api

I am having one API in that all location id’s and their respective info like(address, Lat, long) present. But if I want to fetch other extra attributes like location name, location area, location access then I need to give location id one by one as parameter in API to fetch their respective extra attributes.

I have written below code.but the problem with below code is the data is coming in console and i don't know how to take this information in json and then convert it into text file.

```
ids=location_id_df["id"] #stored location id in dataframe 

authorization =”####################### "

print("started")  
def test_api(url, authorization, rawfile,ids):

    for i in range(0,1000,50):
        for j in ids:
          #print(j)
          try:
              request = urllib.request.Request('https:….. /locations/{}'.format(j)+"? 
                                                                                  
                                      offset="+str(i),headers={'authorization':authorization})
             
               
              response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
              print(response)
              
    
                
          except HTTPError as e:
              print(e)
              sys.exit(0)
              
        with open(rawfile + "_offset_" + str(i) + ".json", "wb") as json_download:
            json_download.write(response)
test_api(url, authorization, rawfile,ids)
```

I need to fectch response in json like

```
5182021_offset_0.json #contains some location id's with extra attribute data                                         
5182021_offset_50.json #contains some location id's with extra attribute data   
5182021_offset_100.json  #contains some location id's with extra attribute data   
........................  
.......................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your example that queries an api that returns json and saves each result to a file.

```py
import urllib.request
import json

for i in range(2):
    responses = []
    for j in range(3):
        request = urllib.request.Request("https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/")
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        if response.status == 200:
            try:
                response_bytes = response.read()
            finally:
                response.close()
            response_string = response_bytes.decode("utf8")
            response_data = json.loads(response_string)
            responses.append(response_data)

    file_name = "data-{}.json".format(i)
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        json.dump(responses, f)
```

I would suggest using the [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/index.html) library as it tends to have a simpler api than urllib, and is widely used by the python community.  Here is the same example with the [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/index.html) library.

```py
import requests
import json


for i in range(2):
    responses = []
    for j in range(3):
        response = requests.get("https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/")
        if response.status_code == 200:
            response_data = response.json()
            responses.append(response_data)

    file_name = "data-{}.json".format(i)
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        json.dump(responses, f)
```

Comment: above code creating many json files.It is creating one json for one location.I am having more than 1000 location so it is creating around 1000 json files.I need output like 1st json conatins n location then 2nd json contains another n locations and so on..like I mention in question

Comment: updated answer to return i files containing j items

Comment: above code generating error TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable

Comment: is it possible to fetch only location id's from response?

Comment: sure.  In my examples `response_data` is a dictionary.  instead of appending the entire dictionary you can append a dictionary with responses.append({"id": response_data["location_id"]}) or if you just want the ids responses.append(response_data["location_id"]).